# refinerycms 2.0.3, how adding a field only to the home page

Tags: refinerycms

In Refinery 2.0.3, i would like add a field (text) only to the home page.

I find it [Custom fields in Refinery CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097176/custom-fields-in-refinery-cms), but if i understand, the field is applied on all pages.

Someone have an idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in your `/config/initializers/refinery/pages.rb`

uncomment `# config.new_page_parts = false`

into `config.new_page_parts = true`.

Restart your server, and then you can see in the back-end page editor you are now able to add new content field as many as you want in addition to the existing body/sidebody tab field. So in your `home.html.erb` you can call in the newly created field with `<%= @page.content_for(:newpart) %>`

Hope this helps.